# Is there a way to trigger a function when the return button has been pressed when typing on UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

When I use `UITextField` instead of `UITextView` I can add the protocol `UITextFieldDelegate` to the working class and conform to the protocol and add functions like:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    handleSend()
    return true
}
```

Which would trigger the function `handleSend()` upon pressing the return button on the keyboard.

There is a protocol called `UITextViewDelegate` but no function called `textViewShouldReturn`.

How can I achieve this with `UITextView`?

Comment: The "Return" key has a different use in a text view. It lets you enter multiple lines of text. If you only want to allow one line, use a text field.

Comment: I have a custom keyboard input field by overriding inputAccessoryView that also expands into multiple lines and I use UITextView for that. I also override intrinsicContentSize, and set autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight to achieve this. Can it be done with UITextField too?

Comment: `UITextField` is for one line of text. No wrapping. `UITextView` is for text that can wrap and contain multiple lines separated with newlines.

Comment: That is my point. I want to wrap text and have multiple lines because of word wrapping when text gets long, but also want to be able to to hit return button to send messages.

Comment: There are plenty of existing questions covering how to handle return in a UITextView. Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uitextview+return+%5Bios%5D). But many answers are wrong because they don't handle the case of a user pasting in multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

Swift 4:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") {
        handleSend()
    }
    return true
}
```

Swift 3:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") {
        handleSend()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: It remains one of the stupidest things in all of iOS.